# Asp.Net Web API preventing record duplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am using C#.NET Web API for my iOS application but I have concerns about multiple requests arrive at the same time.

Let's assume I try to prevent duplicating records while inserting a new record into Users table by:

1. Check if `xxx@example.com` exists in the Users table.
2. Insert if not exists.
3. Return `OK`.

Actually it's that simple unless web api runs async.

What if related web api method gets two requests at the same time (with same e-mail request) and when the first request reaches step 2 (but not executed yet) and second request will get "not exists" response since step two for first request has not been executed yet. Then two e-mail address will be saved and I will have duplicated records.

Using `lock` on static object seems will solve the problem but it will create performance issues.

If I don't want DB to get rows duplicated, how can I overcome by that problem?

```
UPDATE:
```

I can't use unique constraint on e-mail column due to I already have it on Id column.

Comment: You can have multiple unique key constraints on the same table.

Comment: Oh yeah, clustered and non-clustered indexes. I am confused! So is it guaranteed to not getting rows duplicated? @MikeParkhill

Comment: It will guarantee that no two rows have the same email address.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the email address in your table have a unique constraint then all you have to do is insert the email address, if it already there it will fail, if not you will have inserted a new record.

You need to handle the failure maybe respond with some appropriate code to the client so it knows email already exists.

Comment: Is it guaranteed and the only way?

Comment: rdbms won't allow duplicate entries in a column that has a uniqueness constraint (whether you do it through clustered/non clustered/primary index/secondary index, are other matters - check SO for guidance). There is always more than one way to skin a koala but from the limited info I have about your requirements I would say this is the best way to go as it ensure data integrity and you need only one client to server trip to achieve your goal.